# Highlight text added after DOM loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a Chrome extension that would highlight predefined keywords. I was able to make it work when the page content is static but the actual website I need it for, creates content dynamically and I haven't been able to make it work there. I'm not sure how to "listen" to new content added after the DOM loaded or how to modify it. My last try was with MutationObserver but it still didn't work.

This is my first extension ever and my knowledge of web development is quite limited. Please don't laugh at my obvious mistakes. :)

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Highlight Moderation Keywords",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": ["http://*/*"],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.js","jquery.highlight.js","highlightKeywords.js"],
        "css" : ["highlight.css"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
    ], 
    "manifest_version":2
}
```

This is the HTML code generated dynamically after the DOM loaded:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <dl class="subject">
        <dt>Review Rating</dt>
        <dd class="rating">1</dd>
    </dl>

    <dl>
        <dt>Text</dt>
        <dd class="moderatable" data-fieldname="reviewText">This is a piece of crap. And the guy at customer service is an idiot.</dd>
    </dl>

</div>
```

highlightKeywords.js:

```
// Highlight keywords as soon as page loads.
// I'm using a Jquery highlight plugin by bartaz/burkard.
// Maybe I don't even need these two lines??
$("body dd").highlight(["customer","service"], { element: 'em', className: 'kwd_CS' });
$("body dd").highlight(["crap","idiot"], { element: 'em', className: 'kwd_PRF' });

// The node to be monitored
var target = $(".container-fluid")[0];

// Create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function( mutations ) {
    mutations.forEach(function( mutation ) {
        var newNodes = mutation.addedNodes; // DOM NodeList
        if( newNodes !== null ) { // If there are new nodes added
            var $nodes = $( newNodes ); // jQuery set
            $nodes.each(function() {
                var $node = $( this );
                $("body dd").highlight(["customer","service"], { element: 'em', className: 'kwd_CS' });
                $("body dd").highlight(["crap","idiot"], { element: 'em', className: 'kwd_PRF' });
            });
        }
    });    
});

// Configuration of the observer:
var config = { 
    attributes: true, 
    childList: true, 
    characterData: true 
};

// Pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

highlight.css:

```
.kwd_CS { background-color: #FFFF66; }
.kwd_PRF { background-color: #E06666; }
```

On a side note, I know I can add the keyword arrays as variables and I probably will since there are more of them and the lists are much longer. I will try that later since I don't know how to define those variables so Jquery sees them.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You provided too much code, could you minimalize it?

Comment: Thanks, Kristjan. I just did. Hope it's better now.

Comment: I do believe you only need to add `subtree: true` to the config. Could you check it?

Comment: I just tried it and it stil didn't work, Xan. It still works on static content. Thanks.

Comment: Try to wrap highlight code inside mutation observer with `setTimeout(...,10)`

Comment: Thanks, Alex. It didn't work: setTimeout(function() { $("body dd").highlight(["customer"...etc...}); }, 10); I have been reading a lot. Not sure if I should try a different approach like MessageChannel. I wish I had more knowledge on this.